# Utility pole and angles

Tags: moc

I am using the following MOC from the Internet:

http://www.moc-pages.com/moc.php/8435

This model is fine if the sets of power lines are all in a straight row. But what about at an angle? How does the model need to be adjusted if the lines meet at, for instance, a 90 degree angle? 45 degrees? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pole itself can be rotated on almost every level, so that’s nothing you need to worry about.

Additionally, you may want your cables to be parallel. To achieve this, you need to increase the width of your bars, or more specifically, the distance between the cable supporters.
If your distance between the supporters for a straight line is *d* and you want an angle of *θ,* you need a distance of *d*/cos(*θ*/2) at the angle, which can be obtained using trigonometry:

[image: Illustration of geometric situation (top view)]

So, for an angle of *θ*=45°, you need to increase your distance by a factor of 1.08. For *θ*=90°, it’s a factor of √2 = 1.41.

The obvious items to adjust the distance are 1×1 round bricks and plates. Also, you obviously can only approximate the perfect distance with bricks in most cases, but the inaccuracy will be negligible.

Comment: *And you definitely won't be able to able to increase the distance by a factor of √2* – See my edit. Also, you could technically switch to moving some pieces along Technic axles, where the only limit to your accuracy is your motor abilities. Finally, assuming ideally shaped and connected pieces, √2 is actually possible by zig-zagging – it doesn’t look good though.

Comment: Is it important that there are four lines on the pole? Is each line on a separate circuit, or are they in pairs?

Comment: Also, are brown axles common?

Comment: @posfan12: *Is it important that there are four lines on the pole? Is each line on a separate circuit, or are they in pairs?* – I am really not sure what you are aiming at, but I see no reason to treat the second level of lines differently than the first one.

Comment: @posfan12: *are brown axles common?* – [Brown is one of the more common colours for axles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3707&C=8). That being said, I really would’t go for such a solution as you won’t be able too tell the difference in accuracy.

Comment: My question was more with regard to how power lines work in real life. Is each cable a separate source of power? Or do the cables work in pairs, where one is negative and the other is positive?

Comment: @posfan12: You usually have [three phases for power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power) and one neutral. Either way, this is beyond the scope of this site.