# The route of a major power line with branching smaller lines

Tags: moc

In [this discussion](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9672/utility-pole-and-angles) I was shown a diagram of how to bend a single power line around a street corner.

[image]
[image]

However, what if I have a straight major line with several minor lines branching off at right angles? How do I build/orient the utility poles in these cases? Thanks.

Comment: Look at real poles and see how they do it.

Answer (score 3):

The first photo in the Wikipedia entry for "utility pole" shows additional horizontal bars for the respective branches. Single lines are attached directly to the main pole. I think on this scale you don't have to worry about how realistic the setup is (i.e. how the branching lines are connected to the main lines, how the transformers are connected, etc.).